# compare a date from a file in column to current date and print the out as a new column

Tags: unix, awk

I have the input as 11 column file with ; separated.

```
ARM5914447;2023-10-17 18:05:38;2023-10-19 16:11:29;Missing name;Reassigned; Release;Mark;.com;p4;Vail;.com
ARM5914448;2023-10-18 19:05:38;2023-10-19 16:11:29;Missing name;Reassigned; Release;Tony;.com;p4;Vail;.com
```

I need to compare the date in 2nd column with today’s date and print the days difference value in 12th column in same file.

i came up with this awk command

```
awk -F";" 'NR == 1 { print $0";difference of days"; next } { "date -d \"today\" +%s" | getline today; "date -d \""$2"\" +%s" | getline filedate; diff = int((today - filedate) / 86400); print $0";"diff }'
```

when just printing diff it's looks good but printing $0";"diff it's not appending the 12th column, what i'm missing here

Comment: please update the question with the (wrong) output generated by your script and the (correct) expected output, making sure both sets of output correspond to the 2-line sample input; also, `NR == 1 { print $0";difference of days"; next }` appears to be adding a column to a header line, but there is no header line in the sample input ... please update the sample input to include a header line

Comment: Does your file have DOS-style CRLF line endings? In the output, do the lines **start** with semicolon and the diff value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I run your script I get the following output:

```
ARM5914447;2023-10-17 18:05:38;2023-10-19 16:11:29;Missing name;Reassigned; Release;Mark;.com;p4;Vail;.com;difference of days
ARM5914448;2023-10-18 19:05:38;2023-10-19 16:11:29;Missing name;Reassigned; Release;Tony;.com;p4;Vail;.com;14
                                                                                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Notice the new data is appended to the end of the lines.

If I convert the file to contain windows/dos line endings (`\r\n`) the new data ends up at the beginning of the lines, eg:

```
$ unix2dos dat_file
$ awk '.....' dat_file
;difference of days17 18:05:38;2023-10-19 16:11:29;Missing name;Reassigned; Release;Mark;.com;p4;Vail;.com
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
;145914448;2023-10-18 19:05:38;2023-10-19 16:11:29;Missing name;Reassigned; Release;Tony;.com;p4;Vail;.com
^^^
```

Notice the new data appears at the front of the line.

At this point I'm wondering if your script is printing the new data at the beginning of the line and you happened to miss it.

You can check for windows/dos line endings in a couple ways, eg:

```
$ file dat.file
dat.file: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ - contains windows/dos line endines

$ file dat.file
dat.file: ASCII text
                                                 - no mention of 'CRLF' => does not contain windows/dos line endings

$ od -c dat.file
... snip ...
0000140   ;   V   a   i   l   ;   .   c   o   m  \r  \n   A   R   M   5
                                                 ^^^^^^ - CRLF ==> windows/dos line endings
... snip ...
0000320   l   ;   .   c   o   m  \r  \n
                                 ^^^^^^ - CRLF ==> windows/dos line endings
```

An easy fix would be to remove the `\r` characters from the file (eg, run `dos2unix`) and then run the `awk` script, eg:

```
$ dos2unix dat.file
$ awk -F";" 'NR == 1 { print $0";difference of days"; next } { "date -d \"today\" +%s" | getline today; "date -d \""$2"\" +%s" | getline filedate; diff = int((today - filedate) / 86400); print $0";"diff }' dat.file

ARM5914447;2023-10-17 18:05:38;2023-10-19 16:11:29;Missing name;Reassigned; Release;Mark;.com;p4;Vail;.com;difference of days
ARM5914448;2023-10-18 19:05:38;2023-10-19 16:11:29;Missing name;Reassigned; Release;Tony;.com;p4;Vail;.com;14
                                                                                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Another option to have `awk` remove the trailing `\r` from each line:

```
$ awk -F";" '{ sub(/\r$/,"") } NR == 1 { print $0";difference of days"; next } { "date -d \"today\" +%s" | getline today; "date -d \""$2"\" +%s" | getline filedate; diff = int((today - filedate) / 86400); print $0";"diff }' dat.file
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ARM5914447;2023-10-17 18:05:38;2023-10-19 16:11:29;Missing name;Reassigned; Release;Mark;.com;p4;Vail;.com;difference of days
ARM5914448;2023-10-18 19:05:38;2023-10-19 16:11:29;Missing name;Reassigned; Release;Tony;.com;p4;Vail;.com;14
                                                                                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Thank you @markp-fuso for helping to figure out the \r character here, your solution works like a charm! thanks have a great day!

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out, you almost certainly have DOS line endings, see [Why does my tool output overwrite itself and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45772525/why-does-my-tool-output-overwrite-itself-and-how-do-i-fix-it), and that can be solved by puting `{sub(/\r$/,"")}` at the start of your awk script.

Aside from that though:

- Every time you call a Unix command from `awk` it has to spawn a
  subshell to execute that command which is very slow and best avoided if possible.
  Given that, if you can't avoid calling `date` then you should move
  `"date -d \"today\" +%s" | getline today` into a `BEGIN` section so
  it has to spawn 1 less subshell per line of input so the script runs
  about twice as fast.
- You aren't closing your subshells to run `date` after you spawn them so YMMV with what happens with a large input file as you could exceed the max number of open "files" allowed for a process. It could fail with a "too many open files" error (most awks) or slow down significantly as it tries to manage opening/closing files on demand internally (GNU awk).
- You're calling `getline` in a way that is unsafe as failures will silently corrupt your output instead of being detected (see http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline).
- Doing `diff = int((today - filedate) / 86400)` will not tell you the
  number of days between the 2 dates, it'll tell you the number of
  86400 second intervals between the 2 times-on-dates, rounded down. So, if a time in the
  file is 12:01pm yesterday and you run the script at 12pm today then it'll
  tell you there are 0 days between the 2 days instead of 1 as desired, assuming you do need to calculate the difference in days between the dates.

If you have or can install GNU awk it has it's own builtin time functions and then you can use this script which solves all of the above issues:

```
$ cat tst.awk
function date2secs(date) {
    sub(/ .*/,"",date)
    gsub(/-/," ",date)
    return mktime(date " 12 0 0")
}

BEGIN {
    FS = OFS = ";"
    today = strftime("%F")
    todaySecs = date2secs(today)
}
{
    sub(/\r$/,"")
    inputSecs = date2secs($2)
    daysDiff = (todaySecs - inputSecs) / 86400
    print $0, daysDiff
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
ARM5914447;2023-10-17 18:05:38;2023-10-19 16:11:29;Missing name;Reassigned; Release;Mark;.com;p4;Vail;.com;17
ARM5914448;2023-10-18 19:05:38;2023-10-19 16:11:29;Missing name;Reassigned; Release;Tony;.com;p4;Vail;.com;16
```

I assume that's the expected output given that today is Nov 3 2023 and:

```
$ date -d 'today - 17 days'
Tue Oct 17 06:40:36 CDT 2023
$ date -d 'today - 16 days'
Wed Oct 18 06:40:49 CDT 2023
```

which matches the dates in `$2` in the input.

Note that I'm still calculating seconds but I'm taking the difference between noon on the input date vs noon on todays date (rather than using the current time of day and the input time of day) and dividing THAT by the number of seconds in a day so the result will always be the number of days between the 2 dates. That calculation relies on there always being 86400 seconds in a day [as defined by POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html#tag_04_16) for Unix time.

In addition to producing accurate output, the above will run orders of magnitude faster than your existing script as it isn't spawning any subshells.

If you don't have GNU awk then change your script to:

```
$ cat tst.awk
function date2secs(date,        cmd,secs) {
    sub(/ .*/,"",date)
    if ( date in Date_Secs ) {
        secs = Date_Secs[date]
    }
    else {
        cmd = "date -d \"" date " 12:00\" +%s"
        if ( (cmd | getline secs) <= 0 ) {
            printf "%s failed\n", cmd | "cat>&2"
             exit 1
        }
        close(cmd)
        Date_Secs[date] = secs
    }
    return secs
}

BEGIN {
    FS = OFS = ";"
    todaySecs = date2secs("today")
}
{
    sub(/\r$/,"")
    inputSecs = date2secs($2)
    daysDiff = (todaySecs - inputSecs) / 86400
    print $0, daysDiff
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
ARM5914447;2023-10-17 18:05:38;2023-10-19 16:11:29;Missing name;Reassigned; Release;Mark;.com;p4;Vail;.com;17
ARM5914448;2023-10-18 19:05:38;2023-10-19 16:11:29;Missing name;Reassigned; Release;Tony;.com;p4;Vail;.com;16
```

That would also solve all of your problems except that it will still be very slow compared to the GNU awk version unless you only have a handful of unique dates in your input. It will run more than twice as fast as your original script since it's spawning 1 subshell per input line that contains a previously unseen date (as we're cache-ing the date-to-seconds mapping in `Date_Secs[]`) instead of spawning 2 subshells per input line.